Thunderbird Email Filtering
I am looking for a solution to filter emails received in the inbox of the Thunderbird application. However, only emails that have been in the inbox for more than 10 days.
Emails less than 10 days old will wait their turn.
How can I perform this operation?

When creating a new filter, select Age in Days as one of the parameters.

Since this filter might only be run when Getting New Mail, it might also be necessary to run Periodically... Since I've not tried such a filter, you might need to test.
Caveat
Since this seems to apply to the age of the email, rather than the time since it was downloaded to the client, the filter might activate immediately for messages that have not been downloaded for more than 10 days (e.g., after returning from vacation).
